# MongoDb + Mongoose | How to hash array of passwords instead of a single password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, bcrypt

I have a json array containing data of almost 300 users. I am using (Mongoose)Model.InsertMany() for saving user data array to Mongodb. To hash a single user password i am using this guide:
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/password-authentication-with-mongoose-part-1

but i want to hash passwords of all users at once. This guide uses 'save' function to hash but as i am using 'InsertMany()' to dump to Mongodb so how can i achieve hashing by using InsertMany()

Comment: Please don't forget to mark my answer as answer to show that your question is resolved

Answer (score 1):

You can use pre save hook in your user model.

The problem is InsertMany does not work with pre save hook.

But using Model.create will call any hooks declared on your schema.

So you can use User.create() method to make it work.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.create

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);
  next();
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: i am using save() for a single entry (and it is working for a single entry) but for 300 passwords at once i am using Insertmany(). How can i hash 300 passwords at once?

Comment: InsertMany() does not trigger pre save hook

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I managed to pull it off, being that Mongoose pre-hooks don't fire when `insertMany()` is called. Brought in the pre-hook functionality into the seed file, and looped through the data, hashing each password BEFORE passing it to insertMany.

```
  const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
  const userData = require(`./userData.js`)
  const saltRounds = 10;

  const usersWithHashedPasswordsPromiseArray = userData.map(
    async (user) => {
      let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, saltRounds);
      user.password = hashedPassword;
      return user;
  })

  const usersWithHashedPasswords = await Promise.all(usersWithHashedPasswordsPromiseArray)

  const users = await User.insertMany(usersWithHashedPasswords)

  console.log(users)
  console.log('users seeded');
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose `insertMany()` doesn't trigger the `.save()` hook. So, you should hash all the passwords first then use `insertMany()` function to insert them into database.

Comment: Exactly ! insertMany() doesn't trigger the .save() hook. As i am a beginner, can you please tell me how can i hash 300 passwords ? Is there a shortcut or do i have to do it one by one. Because it is working for a single document as i am using .save for it

Answer (score 0):

you have to create `pre` hooks on mongoose that will call before creating a document, in `pre hook` function you can use `bcrypt` a node library generate a hash string.

Comment: i am using pre hooks and it is working for a single entry but how about an array of passwords. how to hash all of them at once as i am using InsertMany() instead of save()

Comment: insertMany !== save. If you want pre save hooks to be called, use create() or in insertMany you have to iterate the array and assign a hashed password and then user insertMany

Comment: I am a beginner so can you write some code for me ?

Comment: you can check `bcrypt` document for creating a hashed password, then from an array that contains 300 users loop through assign each user one new hashed password and do insertmany operation